# Android animation GIF is slowly working

Tags: android, animated-gif

I am using animated GIF to show progress, I set GIF to image view and show it using Dialog.

Here is my Dialog with GIF.

```
public class SimplifyaProgressDialog extends Dialog {
public SimplifyaProgressDialog(@NonNull Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    Window window = this.getWindow();
    if (null != window) {
        getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    }
    this.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    this.setCancelable(false);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.progress_dialog);
    ImageView progressImage = this.findViewById(R.id.progress_image);
    Glide.with(getContext()).asGif().load(R.raw.main_loader).into(progressImage);
}
}
```

This is a network call, I used in Login

```
 this.showProgress();
        subscription = this.makeUIObservable(authService.authenticate(email, password))
                .subscribe(
                        msg -> {
                            this.hideProgress();
                            onSuccess(msg);
                        },
                        error -> {
                            this.hideProgress();
                            if (error instanceof ApiError) {
                                this.showAlert(error.getMessage());
                            }
                        }
                );
```

Here you can see how I show and hide Dialog, So when I used this animated GIF in network calls, It shows animation very slow, How can I handled this

Thanks

Comment: I am also same problem with glide and now used another library which is working good.  compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.7'

Comment: Thanks @SumitKumar I will tried it

Answer (score 1):

Consider adding hardware acceleration to your slowly rendering view. This can make a real difference. You can control hardware acceleration at the following levels:

- Application
- Activity
- Window
- View

and the way to add it is (in activity):

```
<Activity android:hardwareAccelerated="true" >
</Activity>
```

It is also possible to add hardware acceleration in code.

Reference: [hardware acceleration](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html)

Comment: That didn't work for me